# How to create an FTP user (or use ROOT) to access to ALL websites, current and future via FTP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proftpd

I have a new Hostinger VPS and I'm migrating all my websites over from Bluehost. Setting up an FTP user (**I am running ProFTPD on Ubuntu**) through CloudPanel is quick and easy, but it seems to be only doable on a site-specific basis. For example, if I have [www.whatever.com](http://www.whatever.com), I can create an FTP account that can get to ONLY that website's files and no others. This is bad for me because I have about 20 websites and I want to have a single global-admin FTP account that can get to all of them. This is what I currently have at Bluehost. So when I login from FileZilla, I want to be able to navigate in and out of all my websites and have full access to everything.

I do not want to have to have a different user account for every one of my websites.

How can I set this up for use with ProFTPd through the bash terminal? (I already created a user account and [I thought] gave him access to the /home directory, under which all websites get created, through htdocs.) But my FTP connection doesn't work for that account and I'm pretty sure I did something wrong.

Even when I try to FTP in as root (just temporary) from FileZilla, I always get a 530 Login incorrect error, even though I'm certain my password for root is correct. How is it possible that root user cannot connect over ftp? I have tried both SFTP and plain FTP (don't worry, I'll change my root password later). Always the 530 error.

I tried following [these steps](https://www.bennetrichter.de/en/tutorials/ftp-server-linux/) exactly using an `ftpadmin` user I created and set the home directory to `/home` (since that is where CloudPanel installs all new websites). No success, always the same error.

What step am I missing for the FTP connection to work? Why would it work for a low-privileged user and not root?